# Get h3 text value in lightbox title

Tags: jquery-ui

```
var heading = $("#accordion h3").text();
 if(heading != ''){
$('h2.title').text(heading);
 }
```

I have list items with h3 as title and onclick(h3) lightbox gets open. I want to replace Lightbox title with text of respective Clicked h3. I have code but ALL h3 text gets added to title div.

Comment: what is the name of the h2 title in Lightbox? does Lightbox have an onload event?

Comment: newbie to Jquery... Its the h3 from accordion.

Comment: could you try to better explain what it is you are trying to do? not in code, just the concept of what you want to accomplish, I will try to help you figure it out.

Comment: hey... got that....modified code... its as easy... it was a very basic thing.. anyways... thanx... modified one line var heading = $(this).parents("h3").text()